# How Can I Remove A Table Row From An HTML Email If Form Field Is Left Blank

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm currently working on a materials order form for the place I work in order to save money.  So far, I have about 90% of the different parts working how I'd like them to work.  I am new to coding in every aspect, so I apologize if this is some super basic concept.  I've been searching the web for days trying to find a solution to this, but every time I come across something helpful like "Use this JS script" I'll come across something like, "Don't ever use JS script for this".

So, here's the question: **how do I remove the corresponding table row in the html email of a form field that has been left blank?**

I came across something similar in another question: [PHP: Do not email form fields that are left blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502158/php-do-not-email-form-fields-that-are-left-blank) , but it didn't help much as my email is a table and I don't want an empty table row left in place of an empty field.

This is the html I have for the form:

```
<form action ="testemail.php" method="post">
<label>Tube</label>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
        </tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="tube">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Steel">Steel</option>
                        <option value="Aluminum">Aluminum</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name ="tubeqty">
                </td>
    </table>
<br>
<br>
<label>Brace</label>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
        </tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="brace">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Steel">Steel</option>
                        <option value="Aluminum">Aluminum</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name ="braceqty">
                </td>
    </table>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<h2>Submit Form</h2>
        <br>
        <h3>If you are sure that everything is filled out correctly, then hit "Submit".</h3>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

The PHP looks like this:

```
<?php
$to = "example@test.com";

$tube = $_POST['tube'];
$tubeqty = $_POST['tubeqty'];
$brace = $_POST['brace'];
$braceqty = $_POST['braceqty'];

$message = <<<EMAIL

<html>
<body>
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
<tr>
<td width="143">
<h2>Item</h2>
</td>
<td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="143">
<h2>Type</h2>
</td>
<td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="143">
<h2>Qty</h2>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<table rules="all" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style= "border: solid black 1px;" "border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr><td  width="143"Tube</td><td width="143">$tube</td><td width="143"></td><td width="143">$tubeqty</td></tr>
<tr><td  width="143">Brace</td><td width="143">$brace</td><td width="143"></td><td width="143">$braceqty</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

EMAIL;

$subject = "New Order Form";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-l\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<h1>Thanks for submitting.  We will get on that order ASAP!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this something I can do with a PHP function?  Do I perhaps need to change the HTML a bit to add class types or better `name=""`s ? Any help would be extremely appreciated, even just terms that I should Google search.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just want to check if each of the submitted form variables are `empty()` and if not, append the table row to the email message string. You could do with a simple change to your code like this:

```
$message = <<<EMAIL
<html>
<body>
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
<tr>
<td width="143">
<h2>Item</h2>
</td>
<td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="143">
<h2>Type</h2>
</td>
<td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="143">
<h2>Qty</h2>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<table rules="all" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style= "border: solid black 1px;" "border-collapse:collapse;">
EMAIL;

if (!empty($tube)) {
  $message .= "<tr><td width='143'>Tube</td><td width='143'>$tube</td><td width='143'></td><td width='143'>$tubeqty</td></tr>";
}
if (!empty($brace)) {
  $message .= "<tr><td width='143'>Brace</td><td width='143'>$brace</td><td width='143'></td><td width='143'>$braceqty</td></tr>";
}

$message .= "</table>
</body>
</html>";
```

You can add more `if (!empty($var)) { }` checks for additional form fields.

Comment: Awesome, this is perfect.  Thank you for your help!